# Why it is difficult to use two-stage op-amps at high speeds?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, integrated-circuit

Razavi motivated the design of the Gain-Boosting configuration by stating that,

> The limited gain of the one-stage op-amps studied in Sec. 9.2 and the difficulties in using two-stage op-amps at high speeds have prompted extensive work on new topologies.

[image]
I have tried to Google the reason why it is difficult to use two-stage op-amps at high speeds, but haven't found any explanation. For engineers with experience in designing high-speed amplifiers, could anyone provide an explanation or a reference related to this question?

Comment: Consider the effect of the dominant poles from each stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two-stage (and also three- or more-stage) amplifiers have more phase shift and higher open-loop gain, which makes it more difficult to apply negative feedback in a stable manner.

And this feedback is usually required for reasons including - but not limited to - getting a well-determined gain level, a specific filter behavior, to reduce distortion, or to create the desired input and output impedances.

PS: also for obtaining the desired DC operating point. (As I said: not limited to what I already mentioned...)